# Incrementar e decrementar valor com slider (deslizador)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer para criar uma tabela de preços fléxiveis [semelhante a esta](http://www.host1plus.com.br/hospedagem-cloud/).

[image]

Existe algum plugin JavaScript/jQuery para implementar essas funções, que eu possa personalizá-lo?

Comment: Para JQuery, o plugin é o slider() do JqueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jQuery tem um plugin chamado "slider" faz a função de slider, valor flutuante.

Para criar a propria tabela pode fazer uma `table` de HTML simples. O que o jQuery/Slider precisa é de uma `div` para ele poder alterar e inserir o botão dentro.

Um exemplo seria:

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Ye4/

```
$(".slider-cont").each(function () {
    var este = $(this);
    var minimo = parseFloat(este.closest('tr').find('.base_width').text(), 10);
    var maximo = este.data('max');
    var degraus = este.data('step');
    este.slider({
        range: "min",
        min: minimo,
        max: maximo,
        step: degraus,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            mostrador.text(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Neste exemplo em cima inseri informação importante no HTML em campos "data". Uma linha dessa tabela seria assim:

```
    <tr class="row">
        <td><span>RAM</span></td>
        <td class="slider"><div class="slider-cont" data-step="512" data-max="4096"></div></td>
        <td class="base"><span class="base_width">512 MB</span></td>
        <td class="total"><span class="total_width"><span class="total-value">512</span> MB</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Se der uma olhada na [página do plugin](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) pode encontrar as opções de configuração. As que eu usei foram:

- range: dizer ao slider que é do tipo "range minimo fixo"
- min: valor inicial
- max: valor maximo
- step: o valor de incrementação
- slide: uma função que a cada passo do slider atualiza o mostrador

Suponho que o código em cima seja fácil de perceber. Deixo uma explicação extra para esta linha:

```
var minimo = parseFloat(este.closest('tr').find('.base_width').text(), 10);
```

Aqui uso o `parseFloat(numero, base);` que converte strings em numeros flutuantes. Este método é pratico pois retira o texto também. E o numero que uso aí dentro vou obter procurando a `tr` mais proxima (subindo na arvore DOM), e procurar dentro dessa `tr` o elemento com classe `.base_width` e usar o texto.

Comment: Olá @Sergio como sempre você me ajudando muito! Só restou uma coisa: (Faltou a parte do preço, assim como é no site que dei como exemplo, onde é feito a soma das configurações e ele dar o valor)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes claro. Estou mobile mas daqui a duas horas estou de volta.

Comment: Queeeeeeeeeeeee Legaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal!

Comment: Ex: cada valor do `data-step=""` vale `1 R$` e depois ele soma o total de tudo(`CPD, RAM, HDD, LAN, etc...`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes você tem que ter algures os preços para poder gerar o valor final, fiz uma array no exemplo que pode mudar. __Um exemplo seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/Cu96Z/__ - mais do que isto tem você de adaptar ao seu site e preços.

Comment: não poderia ser assim? **ex:** `data-step="1" data-max="10"` **e** **`data-value="2"`** o *data-value* seria o preço por cada step.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, sim podia, é uma boa ideia. Existem sempre várias alternativas.

Comment: Como faço? Eu sou noob de mais. :(

Comment: Eu achei que fosse assim para mudar o valor de cada `step`: http://i.imgur.com/u8F2zBO.png

Comment: @AlexandreLopes http://jsfiddle.net/Cu96Z/1/ - o valor do step é o intervalo com que o deslizador se move. No caso da RAM não dá para comprar RAM se não fôr em intervalos/step de 512Mb por exemplo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15616/discussion-between-alexandre-lopes-and-sergio).

Comment: Você poderia dar uma olhadinha nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25399/como-puxar-o-conte%c3%bado-via-ajax-de-um-site-que-possui-um-cabe%c3%a7alho-com-menu-e-um ?