# Como puxar o conteúdo via AJAX de um site que possui um cabeçalho com menu e um player de áudio fixo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Como posso criar um site que utilize `AJAX` para o carregamento das páginas ?

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso sem que ocorram bugs e que sejam realmente funcionais?

Tenho planos de criar alguns sites que possuem um `player de áudio`, o qual não pode parar quando uma pessoa ir para outra página.

> Site exemplo: http://www.nandolocutor.com/

Gostaria de criar um site semelhante a esse.

Na página seria algo semelhante a isso:

```
<body>
    <div class="meu-player">Aqui fica o player</div>
    <div class="meu-menu">Aqui fica o menu</div>
    <section>Aqui fica o conteúdo que é puxado via ajax e exibido</section>
</body>
```

Gostaria de receber exemplos funcionais (em código) de como fazer isso.

Comment: Você pode dividir o site em `div`s, `section`s ou qualquer outra tag, colocando o player de áudio em uma e carregando os conteúdos em outra, assim o player nunca parará de tocar.

Comment: Obrigado @Patrick
você poderia transformar seu comentário em resposta? você poderia também colocar em sua pergunta o código necessário para tal funcionalidade.

Comment: alguma restrição a frameworks? como angular ou knockout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para alterar a URL da página sem comprometer o conteúdo (refresh) basta usar o seguinte código.

***Javascript***

```
window.history.pushState("objeto ou string", "Titulo", "/url");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/kFCs9/1/)** do código acima funcionando

***HTML Adaptado com o código do [@Patrick](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25401/11853).***

```
<head>
    <!-- Sempre importe as bibliotecas antes de tentar trabalhar com elas. -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       // Checa se a página foi carregada para evitar aplicar os códigos antes de ter algum elemento não carregado. Pode-se usar também "$(function(){".
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ajax").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); //eliminamos o evento
                var path = $(this).attr("href"); //Pegamos o caminho
                var titulo = $(this).attr("title"); //pegamos o titulo da página
                document.title = titulo; // Alterar o titulo da página
                window.history.pushState("", titulo, path);   
                $("main").empty(); //Limpa para poder colocar o conteúdo.
                $("main").load(path); //Faz uma requisição http para o servidor.
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- No caso, o header é a parte fixa, que não muda. -->
    <header>
        <div>"Aqui fica o player de audio."</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" class="ajax" title="Meu site">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sobre.html" class="ajax" title="Meu site - Sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!-- Aqui é onde o conteúdo vai ser carregado. -->
    </main>
</body>
```

Para utilizar o parâmetro `data-` e recuperar o valor com `JQuery` você deve utilizar o $.data

***Jquery***

```
$(function(){
    var texto;

    //Recuperar do data-value
    texto = $('a.value').data('value');
    $('.resultado').append('<li>' + texto + '</li>');

    //Recuperar do data-titulo
    texto = $('a.titulo').data('titulo');
    $('.resultado').append('<li>' + texto + '</li>');

    //Recuperar do data-target
    texto = $('a.target').data('target');
    $('.resultado').append('<li>' + texto + '</li>');

    //Recuperar do data-meuVar
    texto = $('a.meuVar').data('meuvar');
    $('.resultado').append('<li>' + texto + '</li>');
});
```

Esse é meu `HTML` de exemplo

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" class="value" data-value="texto do data-value"></a>

<a href="#" class="titulo" data-titulo="texto do data-titulo"></a>

<a href="#" class="target" data-target="texto do data-target"></a>

<a href="#" class="meuVar" data-meuvar="texto do data-meuvar"></a>

<ul class="resultado"></ul>
```

Este código irá mostrar lista

> - texto do data-value
> - texto do data-titulo
> - texto do data-target
> - texto do data-meuvar

Você pode acompanhar o código funcionando nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/xd6F4/1/)**

Comment: @AlexandreLopes pode deixar

Comment: Eu testei e houve problemas. Abrindo no meu PC funciona legal, só que se eu hospeda-lo já não funciona. O que pode ser?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, ligou o servidor?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: Como arrumar a parte do título?
Vi que foi utilizado a tag `<title>` só que não está funcionando.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes atualizei o código, porém o titulo ele vai pegar do parâmetro `title` da `href`.

Comment: Olá @DiegoVieira dá uma olhada: http://player.esy.es/, eu consegui, ficou muito bom! Ah! e obrigado por tudo, você foi muito atencioso e muito legal! Vlw...

Comment: Disponha, todos estamos aqui para ajudar, acredito que a pontuação seja uma forma de agradecimento, tendo a melhor resposta ou não, eu estou feliz em solucionar seu problema. Boa sorte no projeto!

Comment: Só uma "dúvidazinha" básica: Quando a pessoa entra em http://player.esy.es/ aparece o menu, se ela clicar em algum link é carregado o conteúdo, por exemplo se eu clicar em **Sobre** ele puxa o conteúdo de `sobre.html`, mas se a pessoa acessar diretamente em `sobre.html` não aparece o menu. No site que dei exemplo aparece. Obrigado e desculpas novamente... :/

Comment: Isso acontece por que com essa estrutura você está carregando ele em uma div, você pode resolver isso de outra forma, todas as páginas contenham o menu e não apenas o texto.

Comment: E como faço para que o **.load** puxe somente determinada **div** dentro da página requisitada ? Ex `<div id="puxa">Irá puxar só o que tiver aqui dentro</div>`

Comment: Desse jeito eu poderei colocar o `menu` em todas as páginas e quando a pessoa clicar em um link não duplique o mesmo menu.

Comment: faça o load rodar no body, cria uma div main onde irá receber sempre essas páginas com o menu, assim a troca acontece trocando toda a estrutura da página.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode dividir o site em várias partes:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <!-- Sempre importe as bibliotecas antes de tentar trabalhar com elas. -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       // Checa se a página foi carregada para evitar aplicar os códigos antes de ter algum elemento não carregado. Pode-se usar também "$(function(){".
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#home").on("click", function(){
                $("main").empty(); //Limpa para poder colocar o conteúdo.
                $("main").load("home.html"); //Faz uma requisição http para o servidor.
            });
            $("#sobre").on("click", function(){
                $("main").empty();
                $("main").load("sobre.html");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- No caso, o header é a parte fixa, que não muda. -->
    <header>
        <div>"Aqui fica o player de audio."</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="home">Home</li>
            <li id="sobre">Sobre</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!-- Aqui é onde o conteúdo vai ser carregado. -->
    </main>
</body>
```

Vale lembrar que isso só funciona se tiver um servidor, o navegador não permite fazer esse tipo de coisa diretamente no sistema de arquivos.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes `window.history.pushState("objeto ou string", "Titulo", "/url");`

Comment: Olá  @DiegoVieira obrigado pela atenciosidade! Ainda não consegui, está funcionando somente no meu computador, quando eu hospedo não funciona. Não sei o que pode ter causado isso. Vou hospedá-lo agora em uma hospedagem qualquer só para você ver como está.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Verifique pelo console do navegador se está retornando algum erro, é bom caminho para descobrir o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Sim, possui um erro na linha 12: http://i.imgur.com/CFs9drt.png

Comment: Faça o seguinte, onde esta escrito href e title coloque assim, "href", "title" respectivamente, faltou adicionas as aspas.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes atualizei minha resposta com o código correto

Comment: Genial! Você conseguiu! Só está com um pequeno bug. Quando você clica em algum link fica só `Aqui fica o inicio do meu site` só o que está dentro da página `home.html` que no caso é um `<h1>`, concertando isso fica show! Muito bom!

Comment: Ficou 100%, muito bom! Como faço para utilizar outra tag, como por exemplo `<data-value>` ao invés de `<title>` ? :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes no html ficaria, `<a data-value="algo"></a>`, Jquery ficaria `$(this).data('value');` Com tag você pode fazer assim `var texto = $("data-value").html();`

Comment: Oops, quis dizer `data-value="Aqui fica o título"`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes vou adicionar um exemplo a mais para você entender o uso.